# How can I extract the uislider gradient color at the thumb position?

Tags: swift, gradient, uislider

```
func gradientImage(size: CGSize, colorSet: [CGColor]) throws -> UIImage? {
        let tgl = CAGradientLayer()
        tgl.frame = CGRect.init(x:0, y:0, width:size.width, height: size.height)
        tgl.cornerRadius = tgl.frame.height / 2
        tgl.masksToBounds = false
        tgl.colors = colorSet
        tgl.startPoint = CGPoint.init(x:0.0, y:0.5)
        tgl.endPoint = CGPoint.init(x:1.0, y:0.5)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, tgl.isOpaque, 0.0);
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }
        tgl.render(in: context)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()?.resizableImage(withCapInsets:
        UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 0, left: size.height, bottom: 0, right: size.height))
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return image
    }


func setSliderGradient() {
        let minTrackStartColor = UIColor(red:111/255, green: 111/255, blue: 111/255, alpha: 1.0)
        let maxTrackColor = UIColor(red: 222/255, green: 222/255, blue: 222/255, alpha: 1.0)
        do {
            bottomNavBar.slider.setMinimumTrackImage(try bottomNavBar.gradientImage(
                size: CGSize(width: bottomNavBar.slider.frame.width, height: 2),
            colorSet: [minTrackStartColor.cgColor, maxTrackColor.cgColor]),
                                  for: .normal)
            bottomNavBar.slider.setMaximumTrackImage(try bottomNavBar.gradientImage(
                size: CGSize(width: bottomNavBar.slider.frame.width, height: 2),
            colorSet: [minTrackStartColor.cgColor, maxTrackColor.cgColor]),
                                  for: .normal)

            let thumb = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 19, height: 10))
            thumb.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 222/255, green: 222/255, blue: 222/255, alpha: 1)
            thumb.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            bottomNavBar.slider.setThumbImage(thumb.asImage(), for: .normal)
        } catch {
            bottomNavBar.slider.minimumTrackTintColor = minTrackStartColor
            bottomNavBar.slider.maximumTrackTintColor = maxTrackColor
        }
    }
```

In uislider, greadient is set as above code.

I want to color the thumb of the location according to the movement of the thumb.

How can I extract the uislider gradient color at the thumb position?

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a gradient layer and update `startPoint`, `endPoint` and `location` depending on your current slider value.

```
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.colors = [colorStart.cgColor, colorEnd.cgColor]
gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)
gradientLayer.locations = [0, 1]
gradientLayer.frame = bounds
```

Comment: Is it possible to change the color of the thumb without using **setThumbImage**?

Comment: There is a property called 'thumbTintColor'. Maybe this?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uislider#1653132
Check methods `setMaximumTrackImage` and `setMaximumTrackImage`. I think if you pass a gradient image there. iOS should make the rest for you

Comment: I have already set greadient on the track.

I want to extract the color of the track at the thumb position.