# How do I extract gradient color of minimum track image at the thumb position?

Tags: swift, gradient, uislider, cagradientlayer

I want to change the thumb color same as the minimum track color. I need to extract color at the thumb location as it moves along the slider. I want my slider thumb to look something like this, and change color in accordance with the minimum track gradient color as it moves along the slider.

[image: thumb]

Following is my code for the gradient I created

```
func setSlider(slider:UISlider) {
            let tgl = CAGradientLayer()
            let frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: slider.bounds.width, height: 10.0)
            tgl.frame = frame
            tgl.colors = [UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.yellow.cgColor, UIColor.green.cgColor]
            tgl.borderWidth = 1.0
            tgl.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
            tgl.cornerRadius = 5.0
            tgl.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y:  1.0)
            tgl.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y:  1.0)
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(tgl.frame.size, false, 10.0)
            tgl.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
            let backgroundImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            slider.setMaximumTrackImage(getBgImage(width: slider.bounds.width), for: .normal)
            slider.setMinimumTrackImage(backgroundImage, for: .normal)
}
```

```
I tried to fetch color using the following code:

    let color = sliderRating.minimumTrackImage(for: .normal)?.getPixelColor(point: CGPoint(x: Int(sender.value), y: 1))
    
    func getPixelColor(point: CGPoint) -> UIColor? {
                   guard let cgImage = cgImage else { return nil }
        
                   let width = Int(size.width)
                   let height = Int(size.height)
                   let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        
                   guard let context = CGContext(data: nil,
                                                 width: width,
                                                 height: height,
                                                 bitsPerComponent: 8,
                                                 bytesPerRow: width * 4,
                                                 space: colorSpace,
                                                 bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Little.rawValue | CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue)
                       else {
                           return nil
                   }
     
                   context.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
        
                   guard let pixelBuffer = context.data else { return nil }
        
                   let pointer = pixelBuffer.bindMemory(to: UInt32.self, capacity: width * height)
                   let pixel = pointer[Int(point.y) * width + Int(point.x)]
        
                   let r: CGFloat = CGFloat(red(for: pixel))   / 255
                   let g: CGFloat = CGFloat(green(for: pixel)) / 255
                   let b: CGFloat = CGFloat(blue(for: pixel))  / 255
                   let a: CGFloat = CGFloat(alpha(for: pixel)) / 255
        
                return UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
               }
        
               private func alpha(for pixelData: UInt32) -> UInt8 {
                   return UInt8((pixelData >> 24) & 255)
               }
        
               private func red(for pixelData: UInt32) -> UInt8 {
                   return UInt8((pixelData >> 16) & 255)
               }
        
               private func green(for pixelData: UInt32) -> UInt8 {
                   return UInt8((pixelData >> 8) & 255)
               }
        
               private func blue(for pixelData: UInt32) -> UInt8 {
                   return UInt8((pixelData >> 0) & 255)
               }
        
               private func rgba(red: UInt8, green: UInt8, blue: UInt8, alpha: UInt8) -> UInt32 {
                   return (UInt32(alpha) << 24) | (UInt32(red) << 16) | (UInt32(green) << 8) | (UInt32(blue) << 0)
}
```

Here is a similar question I found on stack overflow for more reference:

[How can I extract the uislider gradient color at the thumb position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61245332/how-can-i-extract-the-uislider-gradient-color-at-the-thumb-position)

I tried extracting pixel color from the image but it gives me only white, gray, and darker gray shades but my track has colors ranging from black to green.

I'm getting output like this:

[image: ss 1]

[image: ss 2]

Comment: The default color is not a gradient... *"I want my slider thumb to look something like this..."* -- Is that **exactly** what you want? If it's something else, show us the code you're using to create a "gradient minimum track"

Comment: Why do you need to get the color from the track color? The desired hue is simply the current slider value in the range 0.0 - 1.0.

Comment: You _created_ the gradient. You did not tell us _how_ you created it, so it's impossible to give specific help, but the simple fact is that it is impossible for you _not_ to know what color the gradient is at any given point, because it's _your gradient_. So really there is no question to answer here.

Comment: Hi @DonMag, I have added the code and output I'm getting in the question. Could you please take a look at it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is how you're determining the `point` for your color.

The code you show:

```
let color = sliderRating.minimumTrackImage(for: .normal)?.getPixelColor(point: CGPoint(x: Int(sender.value), y: 1))
```

is difficult to debug.

Let's split that up:

```
    // safely unwrap the optional to make sure we get a valid image
    if let minImg = sender.minimumTrackImage(for: .normal) {
        let x = Int(sender.value)
        let y = 1
        let point = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
        
        // to debug this:
        print("point:", point)

        // safely unwrap the optional returned color
        if let color = minImg.getPixelColor(pos: point) {
            // do something with color
        }
    }
```

By default, a slider has values between `0.0` and `1.0`. So as you drag the thumb, you'll see this output in the debug console:

```
// lots of these
point: (0.0, 1.0)
point: (0.0, 1.0)
point: (0.0, 1.0)
point: (0.0, 1.0)
point: (0.0, 1.0)
// then when you final get all the way to the right
point: (1.0, 1.0)
```

As you see, you're not getting the point that you want on your image.

You don't mention it, but if did something like this:

```
    sliderRating.minimumValue = 100
    sliderRating.maximumValue = 120
```

Your `x` will range from `100` to `120`. Again, not the point you want.

Instead of using the `.value`, you want to get the horizontal center of the thumb **rect** for `x`, and the vertical center of the **image size** for `y`.

Try it like this:

```
@objc func sliderRatingValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {

    // get the slider's trackRect
    let trackR = sender.trackRect(forBounds: sender.bounds)
    // get the slider's thumbRect
    let thumbR = sender.thumbRect(forBounds: sender.bounds, trackRect: trackR, value: sender.value)

    // get the slider's minimumTrackImage
    if let minImg = sender.minimumTrackImage(for: .normal) {
        // we want point.x to be thumb rect's midX
        // we want point.y to be 1/2 the height of the min track image
        let point = CGPoint(x: thumbR.midX, y: minImg.size.height * 0.5)

        // for debugging:
        print("point:", point)

        // get the color at point
        if let color = minImg.getPixelColor(point: point) {
            // set tint color of thumb
            sender.thumbTintColor = color
        }
    }

    // now do something with the slider's value?
    let value = sender.value

}
```

Comment: Why do this: `let x = Int(sender.value)`? Converting `sender.value` to an `Int` makes no sense. Leave it as a `Double`. Then you get a useful value as the thumb is moved. No need for for all of the code based on slider rects.

Comment: @HangarRash -- Yes, the code I quoted from the OP's post made no sense to convert to `Int`. But, the OP is trying to get the color of a pixel on the custom `.minimumTrackImage`, which is why I am using the slider rects. We ***could*** convert the `.value` to a **percentage** of the max-minus-min values, and then get the pixel location with `x = mining.size.width * percentage` ... but using the rects is a little more straight-forward and requires far fewer calculations and evaluations.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize the conversion to `Int` was in the OP's code. I see it now. I originally thought you were doing that as part of your answer which is what confused me.

Comment: Hi @DonMag, this code worked! I got the expected output. Thank you so much